# slide all scrollViews from tableView when one is scrolling iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uitableview, uiscrollview

Is it possible to recognise gesture from `scrollView` so when one `scrollView` is dragged to simulate same dragging on another `scrollView`? For example I have `tableView` with custom `cell` that have `scrollView` in it, and I want to simulate dragging on every item in list.

**EDIT** 
I succeeded to recognize movement of scrollView, but now I cant set other scrollViews from table to do same amount of scrolling.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    int position_x = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
    int i=0;
    int indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row;

    static NSString *hlCellID = @"EPGCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:hlCellID];
    UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)[cell viewWithTag:16];

    for(i=0; i<EPGList.count;i++){
        if(i!=indexPath){
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(position_x, scrollView.frame.size.height);
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is that indexPath is not returning correct value when i am clicking on scrollView. It returns correct value only when I am clicking on cell space outside of scrollview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, yes it is possible. You need to have a delegate assigned to the scrollViews within the cells. Preferrably the same class that implements hour tableview data source and table view delegate protocols.  You must implement `UIScrollViewDelegate` and the delegate must implement the `scrollViewDidScroll:` method.

Within that scrollViewDidScroll delegate method, you check the contentOffset property for its x and/or y values. Normally people go for the vertical scrolling value, but if you're implementing them in a UITableViewCell, you're probably doing horizontal scrolling.

The you use the value, I am assuming contentOffset.x, to update other scroll views within the other cells of your table! Make sense?

I have just posted an answer to another UIScrollView question yesterday. Please read what I wrote there, it might help you more.

[Animation in UIScrollView iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472880/animation-in-uiscrollview-ios-app/20473480#20473480)

Comment: I need x position. How can I set position of every scroll view from list?

Comment: You need to loop through every visible table cell and find the scroll views within each, and assign the x position from the current scrollview to the rest, but be sure to SKIP the current scrollview as you loop thought the list of table cells.

Comment: I understand that I need loop in delegate method, but I don't know how can I get id of every scrollView from tableView? I tried some code but it didn't work, see my edit.